# iTween not working with Rigidbody

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, itween

iTween works fine for version 2017.2.0f3 and under but when I update to 2017.2.0f3 unity version, there are problems.

```
iTween.MoveBy(gameObject, iTween.Hash("x", -1, "easeType", "spring", "speed", 3, "onstart", "controllerStarted", "oncomplete", "controllerComplete"));
```

My object has a rigidbody and Kinematic is off. Code works fine but without kinematic, it doesn't. I don't understand why?
iTween version 2.0.7

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your code works fine, but otherwise it doesn't. Great. What's the problem? Do you need `is_kinematic` enabled? Why can't you use it disabled?